# What is the difference between \relax and {}?

Tags: macros, tex-core

As I understand it, the point of `\relax` is to stop a macro from swallowing up subsequent material (such as whitespace). But `{}` (`\bgroup\egroup`) serves the same function. Why do we need both?

Comment: Try starting TeX from the terminal without any file name and type `{}` at the `**` prompt you get. ;-) Kill the process and retry typing `\relax`, this time. :)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Try the following couple examples:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{rl}
+9mm   & +9m^2 \\
[+9mm] & [+3m]^2 \\{}
+9mm   & +9m^2 \\{}
[+9mm] & [+3m]^2 \\\relax
+9mm   & +9m^2 \\\relax
[+9mm] & [+3m]^2
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

- If you leave there `\\` alone, the `[+9mm]` is interpreted as an optional argument to `\\` and transformed into a vertical space.
- If you use `{}`, then it inserts an "empty thing" into the formula and the `+` is improperly spaced.
- Only the variant with `\relax` works correctly here, because it really does nothing.

Very similar examples can be used to show that `\relax` is the correct terminator of `\dimexpr` and `\numexpr` expansion etc.

Comment: There is an error in your code, the first `\\` is just `\` so it doesn't compile... and could you explain why is there a small space between the + and 9? I don't get that part (I understands it inserts a 'nothing', but why does it appear there?)

Comment: Thats not _my_ error, that's the StackExchange whatevet that eats backslashes. Sorry for that, but complain to them, not to me.

Comment: I would make also this example: ```\[\relax-5\]``` and ```\[{}-5\]```. The 1st one prints just ```-5``` like a negative number. The 2nd one prints minus with a space like there is subtraction "empty string minus 5". So ```\relax``` really does nothing and ```{}``` makes an empty string and then does nothing like ```\relax```. I understand it in a way like this...

Answer (score 116):

It's hard to answer the question as the two constructs are different in almost all respects so it's a matter of where to start.

`\relax` is a single token, an unexpandable TeX primitive that does nothing when executed.
 `{}` is two tokens which (assuming the standard catcodes) mark a TeX group or non delimited macro argument.

- `\baselineskip =13pt\relax` the `\relax` stops the length parser looking ahead for `plus` and `minus` components, but does nothing else. `\baselineskip =13pt{}` would define baselineskip the same way but then open and close a group which could have several effects, most notably in math mode where it will generate an empty math atom and affect the spacing of surrounding atoms.
- `{\let\section\relax...\immediate\write\@auxout{..   \section}}` makes a command such as `\section` locally inert and safe to write (as itself) to an auxiliary file. `{\let\section{}...\immediate\write\@auxout{..   \section}}` does something but is unlikely to do what anyone wants:-)
- `\relax` is the definition given to a new control name generated by `\csname`  hence the common idiom `\expandafter\ifx\csname foo\endcsname\relax` to test if a macro is defined. This clearly has no analogue using `{}`
- `$a+{}$` produces infix spacing as the `{}` generates a mathord atom. `$a+\relax$` is like `$a+$` and not produce infix spacing for `+`.

Comment: Instead of saying that `\relax` "does nothing", might it be more informative to state that `\relax` tells TeX to "stop doing whatever you're doing right now (whatever 'whatever' may be)"? E.g., in the statement `\baselineskip =13pt\relax`, `\relax` tells TeX to stop scanning ahead for `plus` and `minus` items. That's not the same as "doing nothing", right?

Comment: @Mico I think the form that I gave is more correct. (although it was of course not the whole truth) `\relax` only stops scanning for a length as it's an unexpandable primitive that isn't part of a length, `X` or `\def` would do the same, it's just that unlike `\def` when it is re-evaluated after the length assignment has completed, it does nothing.

Comment: @Mico the bit that I didn't include in the above description is the use of `\relax` as _<filler>_  in `\toks0 = \relax{aa}\showthe\toks0` `\relax` isn't playing the part of a general unexpandable token (as it is when it terminates a length) it is part of the syntax of a toks assignment and absorbed along with the `=` sign and white space so the token register gets the tokens `aa`. (I have never seen a case where this is useful, but still:-)

Answer (score 63):

There is more than one reason.

I'll give an example where `\relax` is good and `{}` isn't:

```
\def\mysize{144pt\relax} % when expanding \mysize we won't trigger
                         % expansion of the next token
\hbox to \mysize{\hfil abc\hfil}
```

When TeX is processing the `\hbox` command, it expands the tokens after `to` in order to find the required `<dimen>`; it will find `144pt\relax` and the syntax rules make this `\relax` disappear (in TeX's jargon it's a `<filler>`); with

```
\def\mysize{144pt{}}
```

TeX would find

```
\hbox to 144pt{}{\hfil abc\hfil}
```

which would be a disaster.

Of course one might as well define

```
\def\mysize{144pt }
```

but then `\mysize` could not be used in text without `\unskip`. A bit contrived example, perhaps.

In any case, `\relax` does really nothing, while `{}` opens and closes a group.

You mention `\bgroup\egroup` as equivalent to `{}`: it isn't; for instance, a macro with an argument that finds `{}` will absorb an empty argument, while `\bgroup\egroup` would absorb `\bgroup` as the argument, leaving `\egroup` in the stream. Again, if we use `\relax` it would be one token.