# "[" as first character in table row

Tags: tables

Whenever I try to compile a table that has a "[" as first character in a row it gives me the error:

```
Missing number, treated as zero.
Illegal unit of measure
```

Example:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{r|r}
        [some text ] & ... \\
        [some more text ] & ...
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{...}
    \label{tab:...}
\end{table}
```

How can I print "[" as first character in a row?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No error for me.

Anyway, you can protect with braces `{ }`.

```
 {[some text]}
```

**edit:** as suggested by @tohecz here is the [right solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86387/14757)

Comment: Yes, this works. Ty

Comment: Put `\relax` after ``\\``, it's better.

Comment: @egreg, for me, only \\ with or without empty spaces produces a table with only one row. If I use `\\\relax` or `\\ \relax` the table appears with two rows. Why?

Comment: @Sigur The original example doesn't show the problem. It's for a `[` *after* ``\\`` that the problem shows. It is cured simply by saying ``\\ \relax``

Comment: @egreg, I understand this. But with only one line, double slashes has not effect until I write `\relax`. So `\relax` works as the content of the second line producing an empty line?

Comment: @Sigur Of course you don't need ``\\`` to terminate the last line unless you have an `\hline` after it. But the `\relax` is needed only if a square bracket follows, instead of your braces

Comment: Please remember that the solution with `{}` is wrong in math mode (`array` and friends), as shown here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/what-is-the-difference-between-relax-and/86387#86387

Answer (score 25):

Here is a MWE that illustrates your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{r|r}
        [some text ] & ... \\
        [more text ] & ... \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The issue is that `\\[1 in]` is used at the end of a line to skip `1in` (for instance) of additional vertical space.  So `\\` is a macro and `[1in]` is an optional argument to that macro.

When TeX reads `\\`, then newline, then `[`, it ignores the newline (as it normally does with all whitespace after a macro) and proceeds as if it were expanding `\\[more text ]`.  But this clearly doesn't make any sense since `more text` is not a length, in particular it doesn't start with a number.  Hence the error: `Missing number, treated as zero. Illegal unit of measure`.

It wasn't reproduced in your original MWE because you had only one line with bracketed text at the beginning and `\\` at the end.  It happens between the end of one line and the beginning of another.

As Sigur suggests, you can keep TeX from expanding this way by putting braces around the bracketed text.  TeX will expand `\\{[more text ]}` the expected way since it doesn't "look" like an optional argument is being used anymore.  egreg's suggestion of `\\\relax` will similarly inhibit the macro processor from reading the bracketed text as an optional argument.

Comment: I think it's much easier to remember to use `{}` (an idiom that solves some other problems too) than to remember `\relax`. But it's nice to know both.

Comment: @EthanBolker It's better to use `\relax` It doesn't make any difference here but if you are using array rather than tabular or a math column in a tabular with `>{$}` or similar `{}` can alter the spacing whereas `\relax` will not.

Comment: Please remember that the solution with `{}` is wrong in math mode (`array` and friends), as shown here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/what-is-the-difference-between-relax-and/86387#86387

Answer (score 10):

The problem is, as Matthew Leingang explains, that `\\` looks for a following bracket for a vertical spacing specification.

The best solution, which works in *all* cases, be they in `tabular`, `array` and even `eqnarray` (which shouldn't be used anyway), is to add `\relax` after `\\`, when a `[` follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{r|r}
        [some text] & ... \\ \relax
        [more text] & ... \\ 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It's a bit of a nuisance, but the case shouldn't be so frequent.

Note that `amsmath` environments don't suffer from this problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
v&=\begin{bmatrix}
  a\\
  [b]\\
  c
\end{bmatrix}\\
[w]&=x
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]