# IEEEeqnarraybox

Tags: tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“[” as first character in table row](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95236/as-first-character-in-table-row)

I am usually constructing nested equations in latex using the `IEEEeqnarray`-toolbox ([typeset_equations.pdf](http://moser.cm.nctu.edu.tw/docs/typeset_equations.pdf) ). However, I noticed an odd behavior that it probably inherits from the basic TeX ingredients it is based on.

Does anyone know a simple workaround for the following?

In the `IEEEeqnarraybox` environment, in a second line (after a `\\` in the previous line), a starting opening bracket will lead to errors. Showcase:

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}[][c]{l?s}
&  \\
[ & 
\end{IEEEeqnarraybox}
```

I tried escaping it with `\\[`, which will lead to other errors, as I am using this in the math-environment.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: I agree with @Werner: just write `\relax` after the ``\\`` that's followed by `[`.

Answer (score 1):

An (ugly) workaround is to insert a space and a negative space:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}[][c]{l?s}
[ &  \\ 
\,\![ & 
\end{IEEEeqnarraybox}
\end{equation}
```

(the '[' in the first row is just to verify that the horizontal spacing is OK)

Comment: `{}` would be enough, but `\relax` is better.