# multiple equations with same number

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

I can't seem to make this work. I want the matrix and the second equation with the same equation number.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
[{\bf Z}] &=\begin{bmatrix}
R_1+j\omega L_1 & -j\omega M \\
j\omega M & -R_2-j\omega L_2
\end{bmatrix} \\
k &=\frac{M}{\sqrt{L_1L_2}}
\end{aligned}   
\end{equation}
```

Comment: If you're referring to `{\bf Z}` as a "vector" or "matrix", then consider reading [How can I get bold math symbols?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595/5764)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually quite a subtle thing that has come up in a few different varieties on the site.

The `aligned` environment takes an optional argument; in your use case, you have been unlucky enough to select a combination that makes `LaTeX` think that you are supplying the `aligned` environment with the argument `{\bf Z}`, when actually you intend to skip the optional argument altogether, and begin your content with `[{\bf Z}]`.

So, we have to tell `LaTeX` not to look for an optional argument, which we can do using `\relax`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}\relax
[{\bf Z}] &=
\begin{bmatrix}
R_1+j\omega L_1 & -j\omega M \\
j\omega M & -R_2-j\omega L_2
\end{bmatrix} \\
k &=\frac{M}{\sqrt{L_1L_2}}
\end{aligned}   
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can 'protect' `[{\bf Z}]` by using `{[\bf Z]}`, which is demonstrated in ["[" as first character in table row](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95236/as-first-character-in-table-row). However, as discussed in the comments, and in [What is the difference between \relax and {}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/what-is-the-difference-between-relax-and), `\relax` is the safer option.