# "Undefined control sequence" on left parenthesis after midrule in longtable

Tags: longtable, booktabs

With this file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
{
\begin{longtable}{p{.3\textwidth}p{.5\textwidth}}
\midrule
label & value \\
\midrule
(2) label & value \\
\midrule
\end{longtable}
}
\end{document}
```

running pdflatex, I get:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...al \expandafter \let \cmrsideswitch 
                                                  \@tempa \fi \fi 
l.10 (2)
         label & value \\
```

There seems to be something about the midrule that makes a left parenthesis invalid.  But with tabular instead of longtable, there is no such problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running into the same problem as in ["[" as first character in table row](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95236/5764).

[`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) defines the rules to take an optional argument in the form `[..]` or `(..)`. The use of `(2)` on the row immediately following `\midrule` is being interpreted as an optional argument, yet it doesn't match the definition that's expected with that type of optional argument.

To avoid this, use

```
\midrule\relax
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{.3\textwidth}p{.5\textwidth}}
  \midrule
  label & value \\
  \midrule\relax
  (2) label & value \\
  \midrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: relax isn't needed with tabular, just longtable; that's the confusing part

Comment: @ysth: This may stem from the fact that `longtable` does some calculation in order to estimate page breaks. `tabular` doesn't do that.

Comment: @ysth -- `booktabs` does things slightly differently if `longtable` is loaded (i.e., it tests for `(` with `\@ifnextchar`).

Comment: ah, it is documented: "There is an addition worth noting: within a longtable, you can use the optional left and right trimming commands, which normally only work for \cmidrules, with \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule (and if you must, also with \specialrule)."

Comment: It probably would make sense that, in this case, the non space skipping `\@ifnextchar` used by `amsmath` is used.