# What does \relax do?

Tags: macros, tex-core

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between \relax and {}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/what-is-the-difference-between-relax-and)

The title suggest the question. On and off, I see macros here in TeX.SE and I see the `\relax` command frequently.

> 1. I was wondering what it does and where/when should I used it?
> 2. Are there any precautions that I should take while using it? (Are there side-effects?)

It would be great if you support your answers with a simple example.

Comment: Short answer: it does nothing, but is not expandable.

Comment: It's often used after some "fragile" commands and in `\if` constructions.

Comment: What you often see on this site, is to make TeX stop collecting for an argument of specific type (very very roughly speaking). Suppose your macro is looking for some number in the argument `\mymacro12345\relax 678` would make it stop at five and then do whatever else it's supposed to do. There are many more usecases but that's pretty much the main reason of its appearance in the answers here.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/what-is-the-difference-between-relax-and

Comment: It is probably the same as `--` for command line options in most Unix shell tools.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Although `\relax` does nothing by itself, it is a safe command to stop expansion of another command. Some examples:

- (plain tex) `\hskip 5pt\relax` -- in the absence of `\relax`, the `\hskip` will keep looking for `plus` or `minus`
- (latex) at the end of a line, `\\ \relax [...]` will prevent what is in brackets from being interpreted as a dimension that would add vertical space

(actually, this is pretty well explained by answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/).)

Answer (score 24):

It is what's called a **no-op:** It does nothing, and it's used in various places where you don't want anything done, but the syntax requires *something.* TeX's rules also dictate that in an `\if` statement, an undefined macro will compare equal to `\relax`. So it's sort of a general-purpose nothing.

(The empty brace group `{}` is another kind of nothing, as the [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/what-is-the-difference-between-relax-and) linked to by David Carlisle illustrates).