# Converting strings to counts

Tags: macros, counters

I'm reading in a number (as text) from the aux file and I want to do a numerical test (`\ifnum`) on it.  I can to it using `\setcounter` and `\value`, but I really don't want to create a counter just to do a lousy test.  Is there a simpler way?

Using pgfmath is not by any stretch of the imagination simpler.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcount\test
\newcounter{test}
\begin{document}

\def\temp{1}

\setcounter{test}{\temp}
\ifnum\value{test}>0 Yea!
\else Boo!
\fi

\test=\temp
\ifnum\test>0 Yea!
\else Boo!
\fi

\end{document}
```

---

In retrospect, my mistake is obvious.  In an expression like

```
\test=1
```

the end-of-line terminates both adding digits and conversion of "1" to a count.  But with

```
\test=\temp
```

the end-of-line is consumed terminating the macro name.  I suspect that the final expansion of this is actually

```
\test=1 Boo!
```

which is legal but too late.  The simplest solution

```
\test=\temp\relax
```

uses `\relax` to force the expression to completion.

Comment: How about `\ifnum\temp>0...`?  Additionally, if you need to operate on the variable, you can use a `\numexpr` as in `\ifnum\numexpr\temp-2\relax>0...`

Comment: Also for floats `\ifdim\temp pt>...`

Comment: You could check into using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) which provides a host of numeric comparison functions.

Comment: Actually, all I needed to do was use \test=\temp\relax.  This also works for dimens.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: The question itself doesn't have anything to do with `\relax`, nor would people benefit from such a tag for this question.

Comment: It is a somewhat undocumented application.  See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96501/what-does-relax-do

Comment: egreg impressed upon me (long ago) the prudence in ending a length (and I suppose count) assignment with `\relax` to close out the operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I indicated in my comment, you can dispense with the counters.  Just use the `\def` as an argument.  If you need a more complex calculation, you can use `\numexpr`, as in my 2nd example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\temp{1}
\def\X{2}

\ifnum\temp>0 Yea!
\else Boo!
\fi

\ifnum\numexpr\temp-\X\relax>0 Yea!
\else Boo!
\fi

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To follow up with the OP's comment about difficulty of mixing tokens and counters, I will post this MWE that works with that mix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycount}
\setcounter{mycount}{0}
\begin{document}
\def\temp{1}
\ifnum\value{mycount}>\temp Yea!
\else Boo!
\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: \numexpr is what I was looking for, but most surprising was that you can use \ifnum to compare two strings or two counts, but not a string and a count.

Comment: @JohnKormylo You can do `\newcounter{mycount}\setcounter{mycount}{0}\ifnum\themycount>\temp...` or `\ifnum\value{mycount}>\temp...`

Comment: \ifnum\value{mycount}>\temp doesn't work, or at least I've been having problems with it all day.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Well I noticed your MWE had `\newcount\test`, rather that `\newcounter{test}`.  Perhaps that could account for it.  I tested my comment before posting.  Please see revision.

Comment: Actually, I had both (\c@test does not conflict with \test).  Anyway, it looks like my problem was due to something else altogether, and I may wind up deleting this question as irrelevant.