# Compiling problem

Tags: tables, math-mode, booktabs

I have had the problem of compiling my document with the following table in it:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering\small
\caption{Thickness measurements on the two tubes.}
\label{tab:Thickness_measurement}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll}
        \toprule
        Tube & Avareage thickness (mm) & Standard deviation (mm) \\
        \midrule
        [89$^\circ$$_2$/12.7$^\circ$$_1$/89$^\circ$$_2$] & 2.08 & 0.034 \\
        \midrule
        [55$^\circ$$_n$] & 0.254 & 0.027 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

I'm using MiKTeX and I don't get any error messages or anything peculiar in my log, I just click the compile button and it just starts working and keeps at it forever until I abort it.

I've managed to make it work by replacing `[89$^\circ$$_2$/12.7$^\circ$$_1$/89$^\circ$$_2$]` with some random text, say `f` as in this table:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering\small
\caption{Thickness measurements on the two tubes.}
\label{tab:Thickness_measurement}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll}
        \toprule
        Tube & Avareage thickness (mm) & Standard deviation (mm) \\
        \midrule
        f & 2.08 & 0.034 \\
        \midrule
        [55$^\circ$$_n$] & 0.254 & 0.027 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

This is probably rather vague, but does anyone know what can be wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: There is a missing `\usepackage{booktabs}` in the preamble and the lines starting with [ fails due to wrong math mode. Can you provide a screen shot showing the format of that 89 etc. rows? Where should those subscripts "2" and "n" appear?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - The error message is generated not so much because of "wrong math mode", but because `\midrule` can take an optional argument that indicates the width of the rule. Obviously that's not the intent here.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for that information, I learned again some important issues. I removed my comment on that.

Answer (score 8):

The problem you're encountering is caused by the fact that `\midrule` can take an optional argument which indicates the thickness of the line to be drawn. Thus, LaTeX scans the string `[89$^\circ$$_2$/12.7$^\circ$$_1$/89$^\circ$$_2$]` for a unit of measurement, and an error message is generated because no legal unit of measurement (such as `pt`, `cm`, etc) is found.

The easiest solution, I think, is to add a blank line after each `\midrule` instruction, i.e., to write

```
    \midrule % insert a blank line

    [89$^\circ$$_2$/12.7$^\circ$$_1$/89$^\circ$$_2$] & 2.08 & 0.034 \\
    \midrule % insert a blank line

    [55$^\circ$$_n$] & 0.254 & 0.027 \\
```

Instead of inserting a blank line, you could also insert `\null` or `\relax` immediately after `\midrule`. (See the posting [What is the difference between `\relax` and `{}`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86385/5001) for a discussion of the differences between `\relax` and `\null`.) A separate solution, already proposed in the answer by @ChristianHupfer, is to exchange the order or `[`...`]` and `$`...`$`; that way, the first "item" that's scanned after `\midrule` is a `$` rather than a `\[` symbol, and no confusion arises.

Here's a full MWE that incorporates these thoughts:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
%\centering\small  %% \centering has no effect because tabular* takes up the full text block
\caption{Thickness measurements on the two tubes.}
\label{tab:Thickness_measurement}
\smallskip % probably a good idea to have a bit of space between caption and tabular
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{} l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} ll @{}}
\toprule
Tube & Average thickness (mm) & Standard deviation (mm) \\
\midrule\relax
[89$^\circ$$_2$/12.7$^\circ$$_1$/89$^\circ$$_2$] & 2.08 & 0.034 \\
\midrule\relax
[55$^\circ$$_n$] & 0.254 & 0.027 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i'm kind of surprised that there's no complaint about the double dollar signs between the super- and subscripts.  since i believe that they're to be offset (as they appear here), `{}` would be a better way of indicating that.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I was puzzling over the consecutive single-`$` instructions as well. I must confess I didn't raise this issue because I can't tell what the intended look is.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this the correct formatting of that lines enclosed by `[...]`, but I give it a try ;-)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering\small
\caption{Thickness measurements on the two tubes.}
\label{tab:Thickness_measurement}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll}
        \toprule
        Tube & Average thickness (mm) & Standard deviation (mm) \\
        \midrule
        $[89^\circ_2/12.7^\circ_1/89^\circ_2]$ & 2.08 & 0.034 \\
        \midrule
        $[55^\circ_n]$ & 0.254 & 0.027 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update with `siunitx` columns:**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering\small
  \caption{Thickness measurements on the two tubes.}
  \label{tab:Thickness_measurement}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l*{2}{S[table-number-alignment=center]}}
    \toprule
    Tube & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Average thickness (\si{\milli\meter})} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Standard deviation (\si{\milli\meter})} \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    $[\SI{89}{\degree}_{2}/\SI{12.7}{\degree}_{1}/\SI{89}{\degree}_{2}]$ & 2.08 & 0.034 \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    $[\SI{55}{\degree}_{n}]$ & 0.254} & 0.027 \tabularnewline
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i'm pretty sure the superscript "degree" is meant not to overlap the subscripts.  they can be "separated" by `{}` (i think that method is recommended in the texbook).