# Altering the bibliography style to encase titles in single quotes and to omit the prefix "In:"

Tags: biblatex

I have an article in which I use

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

The entry for an article in the bibliography is:

> Barrow-Green, June (1994). “Oscar II’s Prize Competition and the Error
>   in Poincare’s Memoir on the Three Body Problem”. In: Archive for
>   History of Exact Sciences 48, pp. 107–131

And I would like it to be :

> Barrow-Green, June (1994). ‘Oscar II’s Prize Competition and the Error
>   in Poincare’s Memoir on the Three Body Problem’. Archive for History
>   of Exact Sciences 48, pp. 107–131

So, single quotation marks for the title of the paper, and no "In:" before the journal's name.

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not a natbib but a biblatex question. And naturally it is possible but you should provide a minimal example so that the code can be tested.

Comment: The quotation marks are taken from your language option, if you use `csquotes` (which is recommended). For the "in" see [Suppress "in:" biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864).

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage[style = british]{csquotes}%
\renewbibmacro{in:}{\relax}
```

if you never want to have `In:`, or

```
\renewbibmacro{in:}{\ifentrytype{article}{\relax}{\printtext{bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
```

if it is only for the `article` entry type.

Comment: Is there any reason you use `\relax` instead of just `\renewbibmacro{in:}{}`?

Comment: It's a reflex, just in case.

Comment: I was asking because I have never seen this with `biblatex` macros before.

Comment: See the posting [What is the difference between \relax and {}?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86385/5001)