# How do i convert from LaTeX, to XeLaTeX for better Unicode listings

Tags: xetex, listings, unicode

I have these as my LaTeX Code:

```
\usepackage{geometry} % Packet für Seitenrandabständex und Einstellung für Seitenränder
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % deutsche Silbentrennung

\usepackage{booktabs} %entzerrt die Tabellenzeilen und bietet verschieden dicke Unterteilungslinien
\usepackage{longtable} % Tabellen können sich nicht über mehrere Seiten 
\usepackage{graphicx} % kann LaTeX Grafiken einbinden

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Zeichenencoding
\usepackage{lmodern} % typographische Qualität 
\frenchspacing % Schaltet den zusätzlichen Zwischenraum ab
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{hyperref} % verwandelt alle Kapitelüberschriften, Verweise aufs Literaturverzeichnis und andere Querverweise in PDF-Hyperlinks
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

It compiles, but i want to use the latest xetex versions of my template.

Comment: You can remove `inputenc` and `fontenc`. Also `lmodern` (this is the default), and `color` (`hyperref` loads it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with system fonts, which I use with LuaLaTeX. This is not perfect, but it works for me. Perhaps some of the lines will help you. Sorry for the German comments.

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,                            % alle weiteren Papierformate einstellbar
%landscape,                         % Querformat
%10pt,                              % Schriftgröße (12pt, 11pt (Standard))
%BCOR0.5cm,                         % Bindekorrektur, bspw. 1 cm
%DIVcalc,                           % führt die Satzspiegelberechnung neu aus
%                                             s. scrguide 2.4
oneside,                            % einseitiges Layout
%twocolumn,                         % zweispaltiger Satz
%openany,                           % Kapitel können auch auf linken Seiten beginnen
%halfparskip*,                      % Absatzformatierung s. scrguide 3.1
headsepline,                        % Trennline zum Seitenkopf  
%footsepline,                       % Trennline zum Seitenfuß
%notitlepage,                       % in-page-Titel, keine eigene Titelseite
%chapterprefix,                     % vor Kapitelüberschrift wird "Kapitel Nummer" gesetzt
%appendixprefix,                    % Anhang wird "Anhang" vor die Überschrift gesetzt 
headings=normal,                    % Überschriften etwas kleiner (smallheadings)
%idxtotoc,                          % Index im Inhaltsverzeichnis
listof=totoc, version=first,        % Abb.- und Tab.verzeichnis im Inhalt
bibliography=totoc, version=first,  % Literaturverzeichnis im Inhalt
%leqno,                             % Nummerierung von Gleichungen links
%fleqn,                             % Ausgabe von Gleichungen linksbündig
%draft                              % überlangen Zeilen in Ausgabe gekennzeichnet
numbers=noenddot,                   % Keine Endpunkte wie 1.2. sondern 1.2
]
{scrbook}

% Recommended: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex
\usepackage[style = british]{csquotes}  % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258860/altering-the-bibliography-style-to-encase-titles-in-single-quotes-and-to-omit-th
\usepackage{polyglossia}    % instead of babel
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
%\setotherlanguages[spelling=new]{german}
\usepackage[
UKenglish,
pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,%                                  Dokumenttitel statt Dateiname anzeigen.
pdflang=en,%                                               Sprache des Dokuments.
unicode=true
]{hyperref}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools} % includes: \usepackage{amsmath} (-> needed e.g. for bmatrix) !! load BEFORE \usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{unicode-math}   %Unicode mathematics support for X∃TEX and LuaTEX


\setromanfont{Cambria}
\setsansfont{Calibri}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}

\usepackage{microtype}   % schönere Abstände zwischen Wörtern und Buchstaben, spart Platz
\usepackage{units}      % z.B. \unit{1}{\meter}
\usepackage{booktabs}   % table: \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule
\usepackage[noabbrev, capitalise]{cleveref}  % easier way to reference formulas and sections
% If you prefer to use the full label name rather than abbreviations such as fig. or eq., load the package with the noabbrev option
```