# How to define a command for putting periods in abbreviations (initialisms)?

Tags: acronyms

Is there an easy way to define a command that takes a word (an initialism) and inserts a period after every character? That is, I would like to define a command `\init{abc}` that outputs "A.B.C." (making no assumption on the number of characters in the input argument).

The intended use is to be able to switch the output of `\init{#1}` to `\uppercase{#1}` or `\textsc{#1}` depending on the desired style, or to distinguish between initialism like C.P.U. (each letter pronounced separately) and NASA (pronounced as one word) like the New Yorker does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the input at each token and then deliver them separated by periods; with `\initformat` you can choose the formatting, the argument should be a one parameter macro such as `\MakeUppercase` or `\textsc`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\init}{m}
 {
  \tanh_init:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\initformat}{m}
 {
  \cs_set_eq:NN \tanh_init_format:n #1
 }

\seq_new:N \l_tanh_init_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tanh_init:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tanh_init_seq { } { #1 }
  \tanh_init_format:n { \seq_use:Nn \l_tanh_init_seq { . } .\@ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\initformat{\MakeUppercase} % initialize

\begin{document}

\init{abc}

\initformat{\textsc}

\init{abc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to remove the trailing period when the initialism is followed by a period, you can check for it and take a decision. In the example I used `\xspaceskip` to make the effect more visible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\init}{m}
 {
  \tanh_init:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\initformat}{m}
 {
  \cs_set_eq:NN \tanh_init_format:n #1
 }

\seq_new:N \l_tanh_init_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tanh_init:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tanh_init_seq { } { #1 }
  \tanh_init_format:n { \seq_use:Nn \l_tanh_init_seq { . } }
  \tanh_init_period:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \tanh_init_period:
 {
  \peek_charcode:NTF . { \@ } { \tanh_init_format:n { . } \@ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\xspaceskip=20pt

\initformat{\MakeUppercase} % initialize

\begin{document}

\init{abc} whatever

\init{abc}. A period!

\initformat{\textsc}

\init{abc} whatever

\init{abc}. A period!

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to preserve kerning, you need to make the test about `.` beforehand:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\init}{m}
 {
  \tanh_init:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\initformat}{m}
 {
  \cs_set_eq:NN \tanh_init_format:n #1
 }

\seq_new:N \l_tanh_init_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tanh_init:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tanh_init_seq { } { #1 }
  \tanh_init_period:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \tanh_init_period:
 {
  \peek_charcode_remove:NTF .
   {
    \tanh_init_format:n { \seq_use:Nn \l_tanh_init_seq { . } . } \spacefactor\sfcode`.~ 
   }
   {
    \tanh_init_format:n { \seq_use:Nn \l_tanh_init_seq { . } . } \@
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\xspaceskip=20pt

\initformat{\MakeUppercase} % initialize

\begin{document}

\init{abp} whatever

\init{abp}. A period!

\initformat{\textsc}

\init{abp} whatever

\init{abp}. A period!

\textsc{a.b.p.} A period!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a really nice solution, but to me it's a little less readable than what jarauh suggested. Does it offer any advantages besides the ability to change the format (`\initformat{}`) anywhere in the document?

Comment: @tanh Apart from the clearer syntax `\init{abc}` instead of `\init abc\relax{}`, you mean?

Comment: That is clearer, but I got around that by wrapping the `\init` command in @jarauh's answer above like this: `\newcommand{\myinit}[1]{\init#1\relax{}}`. I tried adding functionality for handling the case of an initialism ending a sentence (manually `It is based on G.N.U\@.`) by replacing `.\@` toward the end of your code with  
`\@ifnextchar.{\@.}{.\@}`  
but I then get "IFNEXTCHAR" as part of the printed output. (I realize it must be obvious why this does not work if you know xparse package, but I couldn't figure it out.)

Comment: @tanh I added the code for peeking at a following period.

Comment: That's perfect -- thank you so much!

Comment: I just realized this breaks the kerning in P.P., for instance -- compare `\init{pp}` and `P.P.`. With `\init{pp}`, the space between the first P and the first period is correctly kerned, whereas the second P and the second period are separated by a bigger space. I was able to make out that `\@.` breaks kerning (`P\@.` is not kerned correctly), but have not found a way to modify the space factor inside the macro definition.

Comment: @tanh I'll give a look.

Comment: @tanh I'm not sure I see any difference; what font are you using?

Comment: That's strange. I use Latin Modern and Palatino with pdflatex on the latest TeXLive distribution on a Mac. Compiling the bottom code you included above, with the only difference being I add `\usepackage{mathpazo}` and replace the body with  
    `\begin{document}`  
      `\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont`  
      `P.P. \par`  
      `\init{pp} \par`  
      `\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont`  
      `P.P. \par`  
      `\init{pp}`  
    `\end{document}`  
produces this output (vertical lines added manually): http://i.imgur.com/NiUN79p.png. (Sorry about the formatting!)

Comment: It's not a big deal of course, but pretty noticeable with certain combinations of letters.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\init}[1]{%
  \let\nextinit=\relax
  \if\relax\noexpand#1\relax\else#1.\let\nextinit=\init\fi\nextinit}

\init IBM\relax{} is an abbreviation, as is
\init GNU\relax.  What is \init SPECTRE{}?
\end{document}
```

`\init` is now defined as a function that takes a single argument.  Thus, in `\init IBM`, first, only the `I` will be the argument to `\init`.  The idea is that `\init` checks whether its argument equals `\relax`.  If yes, it does nothing and stops.  If not, then it prints the argument plus a ., and it replicates itself.  Thus it continues, until it meets a `\relax`.  It also stops at `{}` (even though [that's not strictly speeking a `\relax`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/what-is-the-difference-between-relax-and), but well).

You could also try to implement other stopping criteria, such as a special character, using `\@ifnextchar`, see [Understanding \@ifnextchar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57788/understanding-ifnextchar).

Comment: That's very concise and works really well. I wrapped your `\init` command an a new command `\myinit`:  
`\newcommand{\myinit}[1]{\init #1\relax{}}`
That way, I can can call `\myinit{gnu}` and make it easier to redefine the output format later. Thank you!  
(Edit: repeatedly and accidentally pressing return.)

Comment: I guess that should be  
`\newcommand{\myinit}[1]{\init#1\relax{}\@}`
where the added `\@` ensures a non-end-of-sentence space, as far as I know.

Comment: However, the `\@` will also add a space if you write it at the end of a sentence before the punctuation mark.

Comment: True. I guess the right thing to do is to print a `\@.` if the argument equals `.` (indicating the abbreviation is at the end of a sentence, as in `It is based on \init GNU.`, which should expand to `It is based on G.N.U\@.`), and if not do the above. I tried modifying your code to do that, but do not have the skills.