# Command "Let\newpage\relax" cuts my bibliography!

Tags: bibliographies

I' have used Latex to write my M2 Master, and I must say it is a fantastic tool, but as a complete noob I had a lot of hard time finding and understanding which commands I needed for what purpose. Anyway I ended up with something that I liked in the end. Yet just yesterday, checking my bibliography to get a reference for the thesis I am now preparing... I noticed that some references missed at the end of my bibliography, more precisely that my bibliography was interrupted before my Webography began.

[image: See, there's a coma after "2012" and before the webography, which means that there are references missing]

So I searched for a little moment, and then I analyzed the code section where the bibliography is supposed to be printed:

```
\defbibfilter{web}{
    type=misc or
    type=online
}

{\let\newpage\relax
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Bibliographie},nottype=misc, nottype=online]}
{\let\newpage\relax
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Webographie},filter=web]}

\newpage
\listoffigures

\newpage
```

At the end of my bibliography print, and just before the print of the webography, I have this \let\newpage\relax command. As I have written this months ago, I didn't remember why I had written that XD, so I replaced by

```
\newpage
```

Complied and...pouf! my bibliography wasn't cut anymore.

[image]

So yes, basically I have solved my problem alone, but I didn't understand why the command \let\newpage\relax created that bug. Moreover, replacing all occurrences of that command by "\newpage" doesn't change a thing.

**So my question: can someone explain me what exactly does \let\newpage\relax do, and why in my case it did cut my bibliography before the end?**

Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Well you are "letting" the macro `\newpage` do what `\relax` does... It cannot have good consequences, as you can imagine. I can't explain exactly what goes on there, especially in the absence of the remaining of your code. But I wonder how you came to include that "piece" in your document...

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer! By reading it I realize how much of a noob I am, since I don't understand what you mean by "I'm letting the macro \new page do what \relax does. Hem...Do I make a fool of myself if I ask what a macro is...? Maybe we should start with that :/

As to how I ended up using that piece, it's probably because I looked for a way to force the next section to be on a newpage, and I probably stumbled upon that piece of code somewhere on a forum...!

Comment: Let's call it a "command", that's the unit that passes instructions to LaTeX. Well you have there a command called `\newpage`, it is easy to assume what it does. `\relax` is more intricate, but you can also suppose well what it does. `\let` is a way to define/redefine a command. So, what you are doing there is redefining `\newpage` to do what `\relax` does. As you group this with braces alongside your bibliography, that redefinition is local. So, you are sort of saying "While in the bibliography, instead of starting a new page, just relax!" So LaTeX does.  ;)

Comment: All right I think I'm starting to understand a little better thank you :) yet it is not that clear for me to suppose what "relax" does. Even reading this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/what-is-the-difference-between-relax-and and others, especially when it's said that it's "unexpandable"... Is it used to "handle"' spaces automatically within a page or something??

Thanks again !

Comment: Well, you can get from David's answer in that link that `\relax` "does nothing when executed". That should be enough to understand what goes wrong in your document. But cheers to your curiosity! It seems you "caught the bug". Welcome!

Comment: Yep, but it doesn't explain why it "cut" the bibliography, shouldn't it have just finished the bibliography and added the webography without going to a new page?
Thank you for your patience!